# How can I get my information from a search from to display in a table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have a search form on a seperate page. I am trying to get the information that is searched in that form to display in a table while also displaying the rest of the data from that search that is in a sql database. A little bit of background: this is for a library to make searxhing obituaries quicker. Right now i have gotten rid of all error messages and the title and hearders of the table are displayed, but there is no information being displayed. Full disclosure: this is not all original code, some of this code i have found on other sites and modified it to fit what I need. That being said it's possible i could have missed a few changes.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "hfa";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*****", "hfa");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$_GET = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'year_of_birth', 
'year_of_death', 'date_of_death', 'month_of_death', 'funeral_home', 'city', 
'county'); 
    // gets value sent over search form

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['age']);
$year_of_birth = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['year_of_birth']);
$year_of_death = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['year_of_death']);
$date_of_death = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['date_of_death']);
$month_of_death = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['month_of_death']);
$funeral_home = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['funeral_home']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['city']);
$county = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['county']);

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
  FROM obituaries  
  WHERE FirstName AND LastName AND Age AND YearOfBirth AND YearOfDeath AND 
DateOfDeath AND MonthOfDeath AND FuneralHome AND City AND County
  LIKE ('$first_name' AND '$last_name' AND '$age' AND '$year_of_birth' AND 
'$year_of_death' AND '$date_of_death' AND '$month_of_death' AND 
'$funeral_home' AND '$city' AND '$county')");

  $q_res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

  $results = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

 if(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
 FROM obituaries  
 WHERE FirstName AND LastName AND Age AND YearOfBirth AND YearOfDeath AND 
  DateOfDeath AND MonthOfDeath AND FuneralHome AND City AND County
LIKE ('$first_name' AND '$last_name' AND '$age' AND '$year_of_birth' AND 
  '$year_of_death' AND '$date_of_death' AND '$month_of_death' AND 
  '$funeral_home' AND '$city' AND '$county')")){
    echo "Success ";
 } else{
    echo "ERROR: Not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <h1>Results</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Year Of Birth</th>
        <th>Year Of Death</th>
        <th>Date Of Death</th>
        <th>Month Of Death</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Funeral Home</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr style="width:100%">
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

           while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['FirstName']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['LastName']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['Age']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['YearOfBirth']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['YearOfDeath']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['DateOfDeath']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['MonthOfDeath']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['City']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['County']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
        <th> <?php   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 

          while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

             echo "<p><h3>".$results['FuneralHome']."</h3></p>";
        } 
  } ?> </th>
      </tr>
     </tbody> 
    </table>
 </html>
<?php
$link->close();
?>
```

I don't know why it's not printing the data, could someone please help?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: This is a ton of code, way, way too much for a "Help, my code doesn't work" type of question. Can you trim down everything that's not strictly necessary to reproduce your problem? I think the problem is you keep pounding on the `fetch_array` function. The first loop will exhaust that. The rest will starve.

Comment: `if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)` -> `if(mysqli_num_rows($results)`. Same for fetch_array

Comment: and why are you putting all the results in one single table-row (the header)? Make normal rows and you don't need to loop through the results a thousand times.

Comment: @tadman I really wish I could trim it down, but i don't know what's going wrong where here

Comment: A lot of things. You should probably create a new file, transpose a more minimal amount of code, and get that working before expanding it into this sprawling monstrosity. You're running that query twice for no apparent reason, you're calling functions with the wrong arguments, there's just so much chaos. A simple start helps reconcile all of these problems. Use version control once you get it working to lock in a version that's correct, then incrementally improve from there.

Comment: This sort of code seems all too common when you visit low-quality tutorials and try and make the best of the examples they give. A more sustainable approach to learning is to find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fits your style and needs, then invest time in understanding it better. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example of one that's beginner friendly, well supported, and full of community code that can make your applications powerful without having to do everything yourself.

Comment: @Jeff i changed    `$sql`   to `$results`  and it gave me     Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\searchreturntest2.php on line 67

Comment: @tadman I think i'm going to do that, try one output at a time. The reason the query is there twice is because it asked for string

Comment: The more I look at this code the more utterly confused I am. Why are you assigning to `$_GET`? There's no reason to run the query twice. What do you mean "asked for a string"? The second run has results but you ignore those, so they're thrown out. You really, really need better examples to work from.

Comment: @tadman like i said, some of the code isn't 100% mine, what i say was that '$_GET' was supposed to get the information from the search form. Instead of the second query, what should be the second parameter?

Comment: Assigning to `$_GET` makes no sense, that's how you *get* parameters provided in the query string. This code is such a tangled mess that I think you need to start over working from a good reference using **modern** coding practices. You can keep digging here, but it's only going to get more complicated and confusing if you stick with this approach.